# nginx 1.8.1 is not caching with Vary Accept header

Tags: nginx, cache

I have a strange nginx caching behavior. There are 2 responses. The first one had stopped caching when I updated server from 1.6 to 1.8.1, another one is caching like before. The first one (broken) has following response headers:

> Allow →GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
>
> Connection →keep-alive
>
> Content-Encoding →gzip
>
> Content-Language →ru
>
> Content-Type →application/json
>
> Date →Tue, 15 Mar 2016 07:31:53 GMT
>
> Server →nginx/1.8.1
>
> Transfer-Encoding →chunked
>
> Vary →**Accept,Accept-Language,Cookie,Accept-Encoding**
>
> X-Frame-Options →SAMEORIGIN

Another response (which works as I expect) has following headers:

> Connection →keep-alive
>
> Content-Encoding →gzip
>
> Content-Language →ru
>
> Content-Type →application/json
>
> Date →Tue, 15 Mar 2016 07:32:40 GMT
>
> Server →nginx/1.8.1
>
> Transfer-Encoding →chunked
>
> Vary →**Accept-Language,Cookie,Accept-Encoding**
>
> X-Frame-Options →SAMEORIGIN

There are no cookies or Accept header in the first case, but only

```
proxy_ignore_headers Vary
```

saved the situation. It works well with it. Looks like some magic. But what was wrong, what am I missing?
Below are the current settings:

```
proxy_pass    http://localhost:7050;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
limit_req zone=banka burst=5 nodelay;
proxy_cache   cache;
proxy_cache_valid 5m;
proxy_ignore_headers Vary;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if you fixed it, will drop this here in case someone needs it.

In the source code of Nginx there is set a maximum of 42 characters being used by Vary headers. In my case there where 51 characters thus my Vary headers where being handled as Vary:* (no-cache). Setting the maximum to 84 fixed it for me.

This article explains it more in depth.

https://thedotproduct.org/nginx-vary-header-handling/

Credits to the guy posting that short article.

Comment: Looks like this is the reason: the first header has 46 characters. Unfortunately I don't have access to that server anymore to check it.

Comment: Looks like this was updated to 128, according to this [ticket](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/826)